# Include protection/unprotection actions in profile's activity or votes tab

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, protected-questions

Having a record of all actions taken on a site, as is provided by the "activity" and "votes" tabs of our profile, comes in handy very often. Perhaps the most common case is being able to find a question I've interacted with in the past, to see if anything has changed about it.

This applies to questions a user has protected as much as anything else. Users are theoretically encouraged to unprotect questions when it's no longer necessary, as emphasized [in the latest blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/), but in practice they often do not. In many cases it's hard to blame them: unless they specifically marked it as a favourite, the site doesn't keep any record of the question to allow them to find it again. We should help users more easily review their own protections in the future.

> [image]

For personal review, the votes tab is adequate, but there may also be value in displaying this publicly in the activity tab. In the past I have specficailly noticed users with a history of repeatedly protecting questions over-egearly. It would be useful to be able to review other users' protection histories to see if this is the case.

Even if this is not available to regular users, it may be helpful to moderators, unless their user activity views already allow them to filter down to see this.